# React Native show multiple images

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have over 100 images that I need display in my app. Is there way how can I map over assets folder and get image name to display?

Comment: To loop over the directory, you might want to consider [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) which provides a JS-level interface for file system access. You'll also be able to use the docs related to the well-known [NodeJS `fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the adresses of where the images are in an array, maybe store the array in a constant somewhere.
You could then loop through the adresses:

```
render() {
 return (
  <div id="images">
   { myImagesAddresses.map((imageAddress, imageIndex) => <img key={imageIndex} src={imageAddress}> ) }
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: (1) you're using map without a key, [that's bad](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: (2) I'm pretty sure the OP precisely wants to know how he could loop over the assets folder, ie how to list a directory from the React Native JS layer

Comment: You are right about the key attribute, my intent was to give an approximate answer as I was not sure about the precise nature of the problem giving that no code was posted.